# Measuring the area of an arbitrary shape from an edge map

Tags: c, algorithm, image-processing

I'm trying to write an algorithm that will give me the (approximate) area of a shape.

My algorithm is provided with an image, which in then performs a Sobel edge-detection on. Using the edge-detected image, I'd like to find the area of an enclosed space, given a co-ordinate within the area. The co-ordinate is likely to be close to the centre of the shape, but not exactly centred..

If I wanted to be thorough, I'd do it recursively. However, I'm running this code on an embedded platform, so I'm memory-limited. I'd also prefer speedier algorithms.

The algorithm doesn't need to produce the exact area of the shape - something close (an order of magnitude at most) would be OK.

So far, I've considered approximating the shape as both a rectangle and an ellipse, by measuring up, down, left and right from the co-ordinate until an edge is found.

Here's an example of said methods:
 - example image: [image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2341713/shapes.png] 
 - ellipse and rectangle-marked: [image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2341713/shapearea.png]

The green fill is a partial-run of recursively filling the area.

If anyone has some better methods, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: Have you got border as point chain (for example as result of Canny algo)? BTW, there are flood-fill algorithms with low memory consumption.

Comment: No point chain, just an edge-detected bitmap (24-bit RGB). I'm actually doing some of this in hardware on an FPGA. Also, I don't *need* the flood fill, just an approximate area. If a flood fill is reasonably fast, then that's fine.

Comment: What is your real picture?

Comment: Potentially anything (the images is acquired from a video camera), but likely something akin to a fruit bowl - a scene with several different shapes and different colours.